# Query based on user input, return result, then run query with new user input

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to query a database based upon user input, if the data exist then print the data, otherwise prompt entering new data. Upon query, the code only returns one time.

I've tried to use the while True: statement, it queries the data based upon the original input repeatedly.

I would like to query based on input, return a result, then reset query based on new user input. Can't seem to figure this one out. Any help would be appreciated.

```
user_input = input("Scan ID: ")

def read_from_db():
            try:
                c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE barcode LIKE %s", ("%" + user_input + "%",))
                result = c.fetchall()
                if result is not None:
                    print ('Name:' , result[0][1], '| barcode: ' , result[0][3], ' | crew position: ' , result[0][4])

            except:
                 print ("Register new user")


def main():
     read_from_db()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user","pw","database")
        c= db.cursor()
    except:
        print ("not working...")
```

Comment: To be clear, I want to run the read_from_db function multiple times, but each time with different user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick -

```
while True:
    user_input = input("Scan ID: ")
    read_from_db = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE barcode LIKE %s", ("%" + user_input + "%",))
    result = c.fetchall()
    #print (result)
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print (today)
    if len(result) == 1:
        print ('Name:' , result[0][1], '| barcode: ' , result[0][3], ' | crew position: ' , result[0][4])
        c.execute("INSERT INTO Data (first_name,last_init,crew,time) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", (result[0][1],result[0][2][:1],result[0][4],today,))
        db.commit()

    else:
        print ("Register new user")
        fn = input("First Name: ")
        ln = input("Last Name: ")
        bc = input("Scan ID: ")
        cp = input("IP or Student: ")
        c.execute("INSERT INTO users (first_name,last_name,barcode,crew_position) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", (fn,ln,bc,cp,))
        db.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE barcode 
LIKE CONCAT('%',user_input,'%');
```